# How to pass function parameters with parameter names to an external program in R?

Tags: python, r

For example,

```
passpara = function(pa, pb, pc) {
    # pa is not passed
    do1(pa)
    # pb and pc are passed
    # passed == "--pb pb_value --pc pc_value"
    # getpass is something I am trying to figure out
    passed = getpass(pb, pc)
    system(paste("cmd", passed))
}
```

To be specific, calling `passpara` like this:

```
passpara(pa="dummy", pb="full-iso", pc="always")
```

should be equivalent to call this command in shell:

```
cmd --pb full-iso --pc always
```

What would the function `getpass` look like in this case?

I also think the `system` function is inconvenient sometimes, since it receive a string and you
have to delimit arguments manually,
is there something similar to python's `subprocess.call()` in R?
In python you can do `subprocess.call(["cmd", parameter1, parameter2, parameter3])`, and
it will delimit the args automatically, this is very handy if the args are strings
that contain white spaces.

Comment: Sorry, but how this question correlate to Python?

Comment: I am asking if there is a feature in R similar to one in python.

Answer (score 2):

Please define inconvenient, and try to provide a complete and reproducible example. We do not know what variables `pa`, `pb`, `pc` are, nor do we know what `do1()` and `getpass()` are supposed to do.

The `system()` call, just like the `pipe()` call, allow you call executables with arguments as you see fit.  I think I have posted answers here using `awk` or `sed` as filters prior to `read.csv()`.

Here is short and simple example

```
R> head(readLines(pipe("cut -f2 -d, CRAN_mirrors.csv")))
[1] "Country"   "0-Cloud"   "Argentina" "Argentina" "Australia" "Australia"
R>
```

where we use a single argument string to `pipe()`; it uses options and a command.

*Edit:* The answer to you revised question may be as simple as one statement:

```
R> passpara <- function(pa, pb, pc) sprintf("cmd --pb %s --pc %s", pb, pc)
R> passpara(pa="dummy", pb="full-iso", pc="always")
[1] "cmd --pb full-iso --pc always"
R>
```

Passing this to `system()` is hopefully obvious.

*Edit 2:*  If you arguments have spaces, place single ticks around them:

```
R> passpara <- function(pa, pb, pc) sprintf("cmd --pb '%s' --pc '%s'", pb, pc)
R> passpara(pa="dummy", pb="full-iso and then some", pc="always or not")
[1] "cmd --pb 'full-iso and then some' --pc 'always or not'"
R>
```

Comment: Not quite so. Imagine I do this to the function you proposed: `passpara(pa="dummy", pb="i have spaces", pc="more spaces")`

Comment: So my my one again edited answer. It would help us to help you if you collect _all_ your requirements at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your complaint about `system`, the help page `?system` mentions the `system2` function in the "See Also:" section.  The `system2` function expects the command as the first argument, then a character vector of the command arguments as the second argument.  So, not exactly the same as what you show for python, but similar, you can call it something like:

```
system2("cmd", c(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3) )
```